# React Loadable SSR - chunks are loading twice

Tags: reactjs, code-splitting, react-loadable, react-ssr

I am adding js chunks in html using below tag

```
<script crossorigin defer type="text/javascript" src="<chunk>"></script>
```

at the end of body tag

The same chunk is being loaded again from the UI script.

I am using v5.4.0 of react-loadable.

Has anyone seen the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I missed this point from the docs. Now all chunk files script tags are added before main script tag.

> It is important that the bundles are included before the main bundle,
>   so that they can be loaded by the browser prior to the app rendering.